# How to access the conf package?

Tags: python

```
! pip3 install conf

! pip3 install boltiot

import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3
import time
import conf
from boltiot import Bolt
import todaydate
import yourdata
import subprocess
import json
from importlib import reload
from googlesearch import search
mybolt = Bolt(conf.API_KEY, conf.DEVICE_ID)
```

When I run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-2fb67ad3a7e5> in <cell line: 1>()

----> 1 mybolt = Bolt(conf.API_KEY, conf.DEVICE_ID)

AttributeError: module 'conf' has no attribute 'API_KEY'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you read that `conf.API_KEY` exists?

Comment: How did you start your app? That package expects to find the config file via a `--config` command line parameter. See: https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/conf